# What happens if you legitimately pay back Mimi?

Tags: super-paper-mario

In *Super Paper Mario*, there is a part where the protagonists are enslaved by Mimi for breaking a vase, and need to work for her to get 1,000,000 rubees to pay her back.

It would take a very, very long time to get that many manually, so in the game the player is supposed to steal the money from a place in the mansion.

If the player spends hours legitimately getting rubees, how does Mimi react when paid? Does it change the game at all to do this through legal means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNmfUY9G1IE) (shakycam) video shows it.